# How do I checkout an SVN repository, overwiting a non-versioned local directory?

Tags: svn

Say my SVN repository looks like:

```
project/
    trunk/
        README
        foo/
            bar.sh
```

and I have a local, *unversioned* directory like so:

```
svn/
    project/
        trunk/
            README
            foo/
                hum.sh
```

if my cwd is `svn` and I `svn checkout http://...project/` I get the following:

`svn: Failed to add directory 'project/trunk': an unversioned directory of the same name already exists`.

Fair enough. So: `svn checkout --force http://...project/` *does* check out the repository, but leaves existing files as they are (and reports an `E` for existing).

Is it possible to checkout a repository, treating the repository as the 'preferred' version for any conflicting files? I.e. in the example above, I should end up with:

```
svn/
    project/
        trunk/
            README
            foo/
                bar.sh
                hum.sh
```

where `trunk/README` and `trunk/foo/bar.sh` are the versions from the repository, but `trunk/foo/hum.sh` is the local version. I'd expect a subsequent `svn status` to *only* report:

```
?    trunk/foo/hum.sh
```

**UPDATE**

Hint: I'm probably approaching this from the wrong 'direction' I'm betting sensible use of `cp` having checked out the repository 'to the side' would do what I'm after, but I can't quite get my head around it ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you're almost there with your `svn checkout --force`. To finish, do a `svn revert -R` on it. That'll throw away local modifications (but not delete new files).

edit: If you want to do it with `cp`, the `-n, --no/clobber` option should do it for you:

```
$ svn co https://…/FOO their-foo
$ cp -rn my-foo/* their-foo
$ cd their-foo; svn stat
```

should show only new files.

Comment: Worked like a charm - but Dan *just* beat you to the rep points, I'm afraid :)

Comment: @BobbyJack: Suppose I shouldn't have take a minute to test it. Well, I've updated with how to do it with `cp`, since you seemed to be wondering.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `svn revert -R` command to recursively restore all files to the repository's version, where one exists. `hum.sh` would still be `?` but all other files whether they were locally changed or were `E`xisting will be restored to the repository version.

You can also use the `svn update --accept theirs-full` option which should also overwrite files marked as existing.